Block, Object, undefined key, undefined function
The short short version:  it looks a function call but is being interpreted as a function definition.  why?
Note: x is not defined prior to execution.  Also these code samples run in the node terminal.  For them to run in the browser you need to preface it with someVar= or wrap it in parens ... not sure why ... but this is not my main question.
I have this piece of code
{x(arg){console.log('Hello '+arg)}}.x('world')
Which seems to be equivalent to this piece of code
{x:(arg)=>{console.log('Hello '+arg)}}.x('world')
What is the reason or use case or history of why this behaves this way?  I can't for the life of me see why in the 1st example when the function execution syntax is supplied it doesn't attempt to call the function, see it's undefined, and throw an error.  Furthermore javascript instead creates an object with a key of the undefined functions name, with the arguments matching the parameters passed, and body as the block that follows this function call.  What special context is this?
I tried to run this and expected an error but I got unexpected behavior. I am aware that an object literal that contains a comma separated list of variables will create an object whose keys are the same names as those variables, but this behavior seems to be more than that.

That answer is about a missing semicolon, which doesn't seem to be related.

Also note that the two snippets you equated are NOT the same. Shorthand method definitions have a binding to this, the arguments object, etc. while arrow functions do not. The docs also explicitly recommend that arrow functions not be used as methods: Arrow function expressions

There are a couple of things going on here:

There is an object (someVar) being defined via an object literal.
Within the object, there is one property (named 'x'), which is a function (also called a method). That method takes one parameter of arg.
Directly after the object literal is closed, the dot notation is being used to call an object property (the 'x' method) and pass the parameter.

It's a little easier to read if you add line breaks:
const someVar = {
    x(arg){
        console.log('Hello '+arg)
    }
}.x('world')

The same function can also be written this way, and it's a little clearer:
const someVar = {
    x: function(arg) {
        console.log( `Hello ${arg}` )
    }
}.x('world')

Or yet another, even simpler way that de-couples object definition from function execution:
// define the object
const someVar = {
    x: function(arg) {
        console.log( `Hello ${arg}` )
    }
}

// call the method
someVar.x('Hello')


I've seen this used with respect to class definitions but not object literals.  Is there something being assumed by js?  Are these two pieces of code I posted indeed equivalent or are they not? I ran across this code in the wild and was struggling to understand it.   Is there a doc you can point to that talks about this behavior ?

@brandon Danny already linked to the relevant docs, its just a shorthand method definition: Method definitions. The object is lost because you are immediately calling the method and assigning the result to the variable.

When you call a method on an object, JavaScript only cares if that object is defined or not.  It doesn't matter if the object was defined in the same line of code (as in this case) or previously defined and then referenced by variable name (which would be more common).

ok, so this is just a corner case of how js works that I've never seen.  thank you for the clarification

It is an "object literal method definition", that's why it works.
See this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#method_definitions
// Shorthand method names
const object = {
  property(parameters) {},
}


I am aware of this behavior, but what I am talking about here is a function that seems to be a call but instead is being treated as a definition.  javascript seems to be using part class method syntax and part object definition syntax ... I couldn't find any docs that describe the behavior I received.

@brandon I don't really see what you mean, the code declares an object literal with a property x containing a function and you access the property x and call the function.

I understand two ways to declare object literals, but {undefinedFn(){}}  is not one that I am aware of, where undefinedFn becomes defined after the obj literal is evaluated ... also , why do you need to assign this to a variable in the browser or wrap in parens when you don't in the node console.  there is something weird going on here and I can't find any explanations of it elsewhere.

It isn't being evaluted as an expression if you just write it like that, you will need to wrap it in parenthesis or something similar to make it work. But still, I don't get what you mean, there's nothing undefined and later defined in there.

the docs you linked to say you can create a constructor function, but the keyword function is not being used here.  is this implied?  why? I understand it does behave this way. but typically if a function is being defined I'd expect arrow syntax, class syntax, or the function keyword to be used.  none of that is happening here

Because it is a specific syntax in object literals for defining function properties. The constructor function thing is mentioned at the top of the docs but my link is for a specific section.

I can't edit your post, and the link didn't navigate to the right section ... this one worked for me though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Yeah, it happens a lot in chromium based browsers that hash link don't go to section properly.
